# How to get the last char in string

Tags: c#, string

So i have a textfile with a lot of packages
"Data.Interface.4.87.2"
"GuiTools.4.92.401-alpha01400"
"Drivers.4.87.400-alpha01000"
And i only want the numbers: So 4.87.2, 4.92.401, 4.87.400

But the problem is the GetBetween method removes the last char

> Expected output : 4.92.401

> Actual output : 4.92.4

Another example:

> Expected output : 4.87.2

> Actual output : 4.87.

> Expected output : 4.87.400

> Actual output : 4.87.4

Method to get everything between "package " to end of string

```
private string GetBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
        {
            if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
            {
                int Start, End;
                Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
                End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
                return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
            }

            return "";
        }
```

```
private string GetPackageVersion(string line)
        {
          string packageinfo = GetBetween(line, "package ", line[line.Length-1].ToString());
          string VersionNumber = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < packageinfo.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (char.IsDigit(packageinfo[i]) || packageinfo[i] == '.')
                    {
                        VersionNumber += packageinfo[i];
                    }
                }
            VersionNumber = ReverseString(VersionNumber);
            VersionNumber = RemoveDotsFromEndofString(VersionNumber);
            return ReverString(VersionNumber);
         }
```

```
 private string RemoveDotsFromEndofString(string line)
        {
            if (line.Contains("alpha"))
            {
                int pos = line.IndexOf("alpha");
                if (pos >= 0)
                {
                    line = line.Remove(pos);
                }

                for (int i = line.Length; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (line[i - 1] != '.')
                    {
                        return line;
                    }

                    line = line.Remove(i - 1, 1);
                }
            }
            for (int i = line.Length; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (line[i - 1] != '.')
                {
                    return line;
                }

                line = line.Remove(i - 1, 1);
            }

            return "";
        }
```

```
        private string ReverseString(string s)
        {
            char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            return new string(charArray);
        }
```

Comment: The examples are good and all but what are the rules? The code will be an implementation of specific rules so you need to know what those are before writing any code. Is it always going to be a three-part version number? Will a suffix always use a dash as a separator?

Comment: A - will only be there if its alpha

Comment: Sometimes is not 3 part version number

Comment: What is the problem? It would be nice to know the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: This code i have here actually works, but it does not show the very last char, so 4.87.2, only shows 4.87.

Comment: *"Sometimes is not 3 part version number"*. So what are the actual rules?

Comment: *"This code i have here actually works, but it does not show the very last char"*. No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Please update the question and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. What the code does that you don't expect or doesn't do that you do expect is central to that.

Comment: 3.3.43.0, 4.92.401-alpha01400, 1.0.0, 4.87.400-alpha01000, these are some of the numbers, that are in the textfile. The code i have written works, but it the actual output is missing the last char. So i what i actually need is a way to get the last char in the output aswell or find a new and better method

Comment: Can you debug the code? What does `packageInfo` look like for the two examples? Does it contain all relevant letters so that the for loop that follows can work?

Comment: I am a little confused. It looks for me like `line[line.Length-1].ToString()` would return `"0"` in your example, but then `End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);` should return the index of the first `"0"` that it finds and that would be after the first 4, the actual output should be `GuiTools.4.92.4`. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Yeah your actually right

Comment: Is there a smarter way to get the last char? or perhaps change the getbetween method?

Comment: "Is there a smarter way to get the last char? " pattern matching might be a tricky thing. If you have ambiguous borders like in your case the `"0"` then you need to choose the border to be more distinguished. Which might be complicated. We need more information. Do you want it always until the end of line? or might it be that the string is entirely embedded like `"Data.Interface.4.87.2"` in `"startString Data.Interface.4.87.2 stuffIDontNeed 22"`

Comment: I will update the post with the current methods i have

Comment: `line[line.Length-1].ToString()` is actually, `0` so you have all characters after `0` removed: `GuiTools.4.92.4`. You, probably want `tring packageinfo = GetBetween(line, "package", "-")` call - note `"-"`

Comment: Ye but not all have a ´´´-´´´ in them

Comment: "I will update the post with the current methods i have" to evaluate these methodsd we need to know the range of flexibility of your input! how can it differ? as long as we don't know the edge cases we cannot really help you

Comment: Isn't this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What you actually want is to "extract" the substring `"4.92.401"` from `"GuiTools.4.92.401-alpha01400"`, right? At least that was the goal of your other (now deleted) question. So wouldn't it be much easier to use a regex like `"(\d[\.\d]+)"` and take the first match?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the `GetBetween` second argument:

```
string packageinfo = GetBetween(line, "package ", line[line.Length-1].ToString());
```

please, note, that for, say `"GuiTools.4.92.401-alpha01400"`

```
line[line.Length-1].ToString() == "0"
```

That's why you trim the *first* `0` and all characters after it:

```
"Check the package GuiTools.4.92.401-alpha01400"
                   ^              ^
               from "package" up to "0": GuiTools.4.92.4
```

Let's use *regular expression*: to `Match` the substring:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

private static string GetPackageVersion(string line) => Regex
  .Match(line, 
       @"\b\p{L}+\.(?<value>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+)", 
         RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
  .Groups["value"]
  .Value;
```

**Pattern explained:**

We use `\b\p{L}+\.(?<value>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+)` pattern to match, its components are

```
 prefix (like `GuiTools`)
   \b        - word boundary, we don't want 1223x be name of a package
   p{L}+     - one or more letters
   \.        - dot '.'
 group with "value" name where we have the version number
   (?<value> - group start, its title
    [0-9]+   - one or more digit 0..9
 (\.[0-9]+)+ - one or more chunks starting with . and has one or more digits
   )         - group end
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "Data.Interface.4.87.2",
    "GuiTools.4.92.401-alpha01400", 
    "Drivers.4.87.400-alpha01000", 
    "Please, have a look at routine.1.0.0.7",
    "Validate MyModule.1.0.0.7-beta1234",
    "Inspect MyAssembly.1.2.3.4.5.6-alpha123 and let me know"
  };

  var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-60} => {GetPackageVersion(test)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Output:**

```
Data.Interface.4.87.2                                        => 4.87.2
GuiTools.4.92.401-alpha01400                                 => 4.92.401
Drivers.4.87.400-alpha01000                                  => 4.87.400
Please, have a look at routine.1.0.0.7                       => 1.0.0.7
Validate MyModule.1.0.0.7-beta1234                           => 1.0.0.7
Inspect MyAssembly.1.2.3.4.5.6-alpha123 and let me know      => 1.2.3.4.5.6
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HPWeIn) yourself

Comment: Lets say i want to keep -alpha, so it would look like 4.92.401-alpha01400, how would i do that? just curious

Comment: @Jepsen_s: you'll get empty string on such input `4.92.401-alpha01400` - package name is missed, that's why match will fail (please, *fiddle*, play with the inputs you have interest in: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HPWeIn)

Comment: Ye i will, i just was curious about, if there was a method that keeps takes in input GuiTools.4.92.401-alpha01400, and removes everything until first digit

Comment: Sure, you can try *Linq*: `string source = "GuiTools.4.92.401-alpha01400"; string result = string.Concat(source.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)));` here we just skip characters until the first digit is found and then concat the sequence (with leading non-digit chars skipped) back into string

Comment: @Jepsen_s: to keep *alpha* or *beta* I modify regular expression pattern: `\b\p{L}+\.(?<value>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+(-(alpha|beta)[0-9]*\b)?)` - now we have *optional* ending like `-alpha123` or `-beta456789`